# How to decompress a single file from an ZipFile using "SHFILEOPSTRUCT"?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

i know this question is asked *1000 times* but I don't want to use any external tools like (*DotNetZip* or *SharpZipLib).*

I have currently this working piece of code:

```
string _from = Path.Combine(apk, "*.*") + '\0';
string _to = destination + '\0' + Path.Combine(destination, "*.*") + '\0';
NativeMethods.SHFILEOPSTRUCT fileop = new NativeMethods.SHFILEOPSTRUCT();
fileop.pFrom = _from;
fileop.pTo = _to;
fileop.wFunc = NativeMethods.FO_Type.FO_COPY;
fileop.fFlags = NativeMethods.FOF_Flag.FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING;
NativeMethods.SHFileOperation(ref fileop);
```

My problem is that I can't extract/copy a single file/folder. If i replace the `*.*` for example with `res\\drawable\\icon.png` it will do nothing.

Can someone tell me how to extract a single file/folder using the `SHFILEOPSTRUCT`? Do I miss something?

The code supports:

Framework Version: .Net Client 4

OS: WinXP, 8, 8.1, 10

EDIT (Notice):

When you use this piece of code in an C# thread you'll always get an 'Path length exceeded' error... In this case you need to use an 'Dispatcher'.

Comment: What is your target .Net framework?

Comment: I use .NET Client 4. (just added it to my question)

Comment: Note that according to MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you should be using the [IFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Vista onwards

Comment: Hehe thats the prob... I need it also working on WinXP... The given example will also work in WinXP. But i can only extract the whole ZipFile. But i dun want to extract a whole zip for just 1 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHFileOperation` is not capable of extracting individual items from a ZIP file. You options as I see them are:

1. Include a 3rd party ZIP library.
2. Switch to .net 4.5 and use the framework supplied ZIP library.
3. See if `ZipPackage` from `System.IO.Packaging` has enough functionality to meet your needs.
4. Write your own ZIP code.
5. Extract the entire ZIP file to a temporary directory and then pick out the parts you need.

Comment: Hey there, thx for ur info! - But, i can't do step 1-3 so i decided (yesterday) to decompress the complete zip to an tmp folder and move the needed file(s)/folder(s) manually. - About the self-made zip-wrapper this my next project. ;) - However, MUCH THX to u for this really helpful hint!

Answer (score 18):

.NET 4.5 has [native ZIP support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx), you should try that

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries.Where(e => e.FullName.Contains("a")))
    {
        entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for the example code, but i can't switch to an higher framework version. Coz i use this code inside my dll which is used by lots of ppl... So they also have to set a higher version of .NET.

Comment: Why is this part there? Where(e => e.FullName.Containts("a"))

Comment: Note: requires `using System.Linq`

Comment: And @RaulMarquez, that's just the filtration system OP is using. This specific example would only extract entries in the ZIP file whose FullName contained the letter "a"

Answer (score 1):

pFrom needs to be double null-terminated:

```
string _from = Path.Combine(apk, "*.*") + "\0\0";
```

This is because it can contain multiple paths, which should be null-separated.

Comment: THX for the hint, but, it still dun work. It still dun want extract an single item.

Comment: There was a syntax error in my previous  sample (single quotes versus double quotes). Assuming you caught that, can you add the exact error you get when you try it?

Comment: Hey :) - Yups i have seen this little issue - NP. - That's the funny issue... I dun get an error... It only do nothing.

Comment: Ok just got the HRESULT... It tells me "87"...
Edit:
Just found this: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164(v=vs.85).aspx) there the error is defined as "read-only source"... But the destination is my "c:" hdd.

Comment: 87 is an incorrect parameter. Those multiple-null strings may not be getting marshalled correctly.

Comment: Hmm that's really sad... Seems that i have to extract the whole zip to an tmp folder, search the needed file(s)/folder(s) and copy them manually. - Anyways MUCH THX for ur help! :)

Comment: @PhillipKnauss It's not an issue with double null terminated strings, the functionality is simply not supported. FWIW, your string is triple null-terminated. The explicit pair that you supplied, and then the implicit null.